# jtable from sql database with search/compare query

Tags: java, sql, swing, search, jtable

Hello im looking for some example of simple table which content we can search by textfield query. I did successful make list comparison, but table seems impossible for me

Answer (score 1):

`JTable` has a filter capability, meaning that you can filter the content being displayed in the `JTable` in real-time.

For examples, take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and pay attention of the [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section